# Ubuntu 17.10 can startx in tty2 but stuck in login loop except on unity

Tags: unity, nvidia, xorg, login

I recently (this week) updated my Ubuntu 17.10 and installed the NVIDIA driver. And:

- I am stuck in a login loop and tried everything at: [17.04 update login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/949456/17-04-update-login-loop)
- I can log into unity
- I can `startx` in TTY2

From `.xsession-errors`:

```
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
upstart: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/linux-image-extra-4.13.0-38-generic.0.crash) main process (2666) terminated with status 1
upstart: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_lib_systemd_system-generators_lvm2-activation-generator.0.crash) main process (6230) terminated with status 134
upstart: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_lib_update-notifier_system-crash-notification.1000.crash) main process (6656) terminated with status 134
upstart: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_share_apport_apport-gtk.1000.crash) main process (7116) terminated with status 134
upstart: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_share_apport_apport-gtk.1000.crash) main process (7816) terminated with status 134
upstart: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_lib_systemd_system-generators_lvm2-activation-generator.0.crash) main process (17901) terminated with status 134
upstart: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_lib_update-notifier_system-crash-notification.1000.crash) main process (18104) terminated with status 134
upstart: window-stack-bridge main process (2656) killed by HUP signal
upstart: upstart-dbus-session-bridge main process (2691) terminated with status 1
upstart: bamfdaemon main process (2697) killed by TERM signal
upstart: hud main process (2809) killed by HUP signal
upstart: unity-settings-daemon main process (2811) killed by HUP signal
upstart: at-spi2-registryd main process (2819) killed by HUP signal
upstart: gnome-session (Unity) main process (2820) killed by HUP signal
upstart: unity-panel-service main process (2839) killed by HUP signal
upstart: indicator-messages main process (2876) killed by HUP signal
upstart: indicator-bluetooth main process (2877) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-power main process (2878) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-datetime main process (2879) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-keyboard main process (2880) terminated with status 1
upstart: indicator-sound main process (2881) killed by HUP signal
upstart: indicator-session main process (2882) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-application main process (2923) killed by TERM signal
upstart: unity7 main process (2986) terminated with status 1
upstart: indicator-application pre-stop process (19200) terminated with status 255
upstart: gnome-session (Unity) pre-stop process (19201) terminated with status 127
upstart: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
upstart: gpg-agent post-stop process (19208) terminated with status 127
Xsession: X session started for nli at joi 29 martie 2018, 15:16:18 +0300
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/nli/.Xauthority
localuser:nli being added to access control list
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting MAIL=/var/mail/nli
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USER=nli
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_TIME=ro_RO.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHLVL=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting HOME=/home/nli
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT4_IM_MODULE=xim
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting HUSHLOGIN=FALSE
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_MONETARY=ro_RO.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=appmenu-qt5
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LOGNAME=nli
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting _=/usr/bin/startx
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting TERM=linux
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting WINDOWPATH=2
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK2_MODULES=overlay-scrollbar
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PATH=/home/nli/bin:/home/nli/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_ADDRESS=ro_RO.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANG=en_US.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_TELEPHONE=ro_RO.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/nli/.Xauthority
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_NAME=ro_RO.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHELL=/bin/bash
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_MEASUREMENT=ro_RO.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_IDENTIFICATION=ro_RO.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PWD=/home/nli
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_NUMERIC=ro_RO.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_PAPER=ro_RO.UTF-8
Xsession: X session started for nli at joi 29 martie 2018, 15:36:35 +0300
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/nli/.Xauthority
localuser:nli being added to access control list
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting MAIL=/var/mail/nli
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USER=nli
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_TIME=ro_RO.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHLVL=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting HOME=/home/nli
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT4_IM_MODULE=xim
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting HUSHLOGIN=FALSE
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_MONETARY=ro_RO.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=appmenu-qt5
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LOGNAME=nli
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting _=/usr/bin/startx
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting TERM=linux
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting WINDOWPATH=2
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK2_MODULES=overlay-scrollbar
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PATH=/home/nli/bin:/home/nli/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_ADDRESS=ro_RO.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANG=en_US.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_TELEPHONE=ro_RO.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/nli/.Xauthority
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_NAME=ro_RO.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHELL=/bin/bash
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_MEASUREMENT=ro_RO.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_IDENTIFICATION=ro_RO.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PWD=/home/nli
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_NUMERIC=ro_RO.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_PAPER=ro_RO.UTF-8
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following this: [Login loop after upgrade to 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760492/login-loop-after-upgrade-to-16-04)

I was able to fix the problem by uninstalling the nvidia driver with:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge 'nvidia-*'
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
echo 'nouveau' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

Comment: the NVIDIA driver works only with unity interface.